# Proving bigO of the series $c^k$ as $c$ goes to $k$

Tags: sequences-and-series, asymptotics

The same question was posted here but I feel necessary details were left out:
[Geometric series and big theta](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/510511/geometric-series-and-big-theta)

The question states:
Show that, if $c$ is a positive real number, then $f(n)= \sum\limits_{k=0}^n c^k$ is:

- $\theta (1)$ if $c < 1$
- $\theta (n)$ if $c = 1$
- $\theta (c^n)$ if $c > 1$

I know that as $k$ approaches infinity this can be simplified to $\dfrac{1}{1-c}$ and since that doesn't rely on $n$, it's constant, thus the first bullet point is done (that's how my instructor explained it to me). However, that doesn't work for $c = 1$, and doesn't prove the third bullet. So how do I do this properly? Thank you.

Comment: In your title you say "as $c$ goes to $k$", but in your problem you are interested in "as $n$ goes to $\infty$". I assume that the second one is correct. Can you confirm this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $c=1$ it is trivial, i.e.

$$f(n) = \sum_{k=1}^{n} c^k = \sum_{k=1}^{n} 1 = n \Longrightarrow f(n)\in O(n)$$

For $c>1$ you will get

$$f(n) = \sum_{k=1}^{n} c^k = \frac{1-c^{k+1}}{1-c} = \frac{ c^{k+1} - 1}{c -1} = c^{k+1}\underbrace{\frac{1}{c -1}}_{const}+\underbrace{\frac{- 1}{c -1}}_{const}\Longrightarrow f(n) \in O(c^n)$$

Comment: Where did you get the first part of that? The $\frac{1-c^{k+1}}{1-c}$

Comment: It's basic knowledge. But the trick to proof this, is to write down $f(n)-c\cdot f(n)$ and devide this expression by $(1-c)$. See also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series

Comment: *facepalm* a geometric series, nice. I honestly forgot about those really. Thanks for your help!